# Text contained in box shows up with top padding in browser, but not in fiddle

Tags: html, css, padding

I have been witnessing this weird behavior since last night.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gqndm/

and here is a screenshot of what I get in all the major browsers on my machine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl3ve.png

Any idea as to why the text appears to be pushed down in the box (e.g. not being at the very top of the box, like in the fiddle).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jsFiddle imports a CSS file called [`normalize.css`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css) with the following CSS...

```
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td { 
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset,img { 
    border:0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style:none;
}
caption,th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border:0;}
```

As you can see, `p` and `div` elements have their `margin` and `padding` set to `0`.

This effectively normalises all browser's default stylesheets. If you included this CSS in your other browser tests, no doubt you will see the same that is in jsFiddle.

Comment: Do you know why they do that?

Comment: @mcgrailm They include it to set a common baseline over all browsers (because their default stylesheets are not the same). So what you see in jsFiddle is more likely to be what I see too.

Comment: @alex Sure works, thanks! Is it a good idea to add this file to any project to reset all properties? Also, do all browsers add padding to <p>s and other elements by default?

Comment: @jonasll A browser reset stylesheet is beneficial. Browsers add their own paddings and margins by what is known as their *default stylesheet*.

Comment: For more info about CSS resets, take a look at this - http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/